# Append extra data to the called actions in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say we have 10 controllers. Each named `ControllerN`.

And let's say in each of them we have 10 actions, called `ActionN`.

We know that **ALL** of them return an object and it would be converted into JSON.

No matter what the output JSON is, I want to attach performance timing to it. For example:

```
{
   ...otherData,
   milliseconds: 32
}
```

Is it possible in ASP.NET Core?

I thought about a middleware. But middleware affects the entire traffic. Thus it might be more suitable to do it some other way.

Comment: I think you can do it by calculating the threads timing. I mean write a code that calculates how much time threads do. So you are going to have a static class for each request

Comment: In the Middleware or filter you can just test if the response is json (e.g. by checking the content type header) and thus conditionally apply the modification. That doesn't have a giant performance impact

Answer (score 1):

You can use action filters for this purpose. [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)

And modifying the JSON on the fly will be difficult. You can do something like this.

```
public class SampleActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items["timer"] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var stopwatch = context.HttpContext.Items["timer"] as Stopwatch;
        if(stopwatch != null)
        {
            var elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryAdd("X-ExecutionTime", elapsed.ToString());
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

[image: Response Headers - Swagger]

Comment: Modifying json on the fly is not that difficult. Just treat it as json, not as some deserialized type. Or if you really want to deserialize, do `Dictionary<string, object>`.